# Prime factorization in pure cubic field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{ab^2})$, where $a$ is squarefree. Let $p$ be a prime number, how does one determine the prime factorization of a ideal $p O_K$?

By Kummer's theorem, if $O_K = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ we can determine it by factorization of the polynomial of $\alpha$.

But I was not sure how to tell if $O_K$ can be written as $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$?

By the answer below, it seems $O_K$ is not always in the form $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, how can we determine the prime factorization then?

Comment: Isn’t this a purely local question? Without having worked a problem of this type myself, I would nonetheless predict that localization techniques should give an answer quickly. Do you have a particular case that you’re interested in?

Comment: @Lubin I was not sure what local means? Does it involve completion? Let $m=ab^2$, could you give an example with calculation in case $p=3$, $m=8$? (or $p=5, m=25$; or $p=5,m=5$)? Thanks!

Comment: Localization usually means passing from the ring of integers to the ring that you get by allowing denominators prime to $p$; and you can complete that, too, if you like. Your example with $m=8$ does not give an extension. Did you mean something else? Your examples with $m=5$ and $m=25$ give the same ring. In the case $m=5$, the polynomial is Eisenstein for the prime $p=5$, and so you have $(5)=\mathfrak p^3$: totally ramified at $5$. These examples are not interesting yet. Do you have others?

Comment: @Lubin How about $p=3, m=10$ and $p=5,m=7$?

Comment: Probably best if we continue this by e-mail. But for the first example, you look at $(x+1)^3-10$ and notice that its Newton polygon has a segment of width one and a segment of width two, slope $-1/2$. This says that the splitting is into two primes, one of degree $1$ the other occurring with exponent $2$, thus ramified. For the second example, over $\Bbb F_5$, your polynomial splits into a linear times a quadratic, and so you get one prime of degree $1$, another of degree $2$, unramified.

Answer (score 1):

A number field $K$ is called *monogenic* (or is said to have a *power integral basis*), if its ring of integers has the form $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ for some $\alpha\in \mathcal{O}_K$. The criterium for cubic number fields $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{ab^2})$, with $gcd(a,b)=1$ and $ab^2$ cubefree is as follows: If $a^2\not\equiv b^2 \bmod 9$, then $K$ is monogenic if and only if $ax^3 + by^3 = 1$ has an integral solution. In the other case, if $a^2 ≡ b^2 \bmod 9$,  $K$ is monogenic if and only if $ax^3 +by^3 = 9$ has an integral solution.

Reference: The book *Diophantine Equations and Power Integral Bases* by István Gaál, Birkhauser, 2002.

Comment: Can you provide a reference?

Comment: Thanks for criterion for monogenic case! In this case, If the ring is not monogenic, how can we determine the factorization of $pO_K$?

Comment: See for example the talk on [Factoring Primes in Cubic Fields](https://cjweir.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/jobtalk2013.pdf)